# warning: 'auto' type specifier is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt5, c++14

I'm using Qt5 with Clang on Debian Jessie. To experiment with generic lambdas, in the .pro file there is:

```
CONFIG += c++14
```

And after building I got:

```
warning: 'auto' type specifier is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
```

To get rid of this obvious message I did:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -Wc++11-extensions
```

But I keep getting the obvious message. Why? How to hide it?

Comment: Not duplicate. The other question is about how to enable C++14 in Qt Creator, which I do by `CONFIG += c++14` (tested in Windows, works fine).

Comment: Usually this warning would only be enabled if you were in pre-c++11 mode so I suspect that your CONFIG option is actually not working

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you want `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS+=-Wno-c++11-extensions` I suspect.

[clang compiler documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html)

pertinent part:

> `-Wfoo`: Enable warning `foo`.
>
> `-Wno-foo`: Disable warning `foo`.

Comment: Do you have a reference for your answer? I see no effect here.

Comment: I do not, just in my experience you need to put 'no' in to suppress a warning

Comment: Yout forgot the `-`, `-Wno-c++11-extensions` does it.

Comment: please accept my answer if it did what you want.  If you'd like to see improvements to my answer, or more documentation, please let me know what specifically you find lacking.

Answer (score 13):

According to qmake's repository history, the `CONFIG += c++14` stanza was added in qmake version 5.4: https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/87831/

However, it seems Debian Jessie only has qmake version 5.3 (https://packages.debian.org/jessie/qt5-qmake)

As a workaround, you can use

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++14
```

or

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=gnu++14
```

Comment: `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++1y` also works here (in Jessie). You went directly to the point. Interestingly, on Windows, where I'm using `CONFIG += c++14` it cannot be replaced by any of the "alternative" stanza

Comment: @KcFnMi Right, those are actual compiler flags for GCC or clang. For other compilers like MSVC, you'd need something else.